# How to implicate UICollectionViewCell Flip animation

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to implicate UICollectionViewCell that contains two different view also flip over each over.
But I have a trouble, when I flip the first collectionViewCell tenth collectionViewCell is also flip over. please help me

FlipCollectionViewController

```
class FlipCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

private struct Storyboard {
    static let FlipCellReuseIdentifier = "FilpCell"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 20
}

var selectedCellDefaultFrame:CGRect!
var selectedCellDefaultTransform:CGAffineTransform!


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("select")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.FlipCellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FilpCollectionViewCell


}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.FlipCellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FilpCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

}
```

FlipCollectionViewCell

```
class FilpCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var back: UIView!
var front: UIImageView!
var showingBack = true
var initNumber:Int = 0


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped")
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = true

}

func tapped() {
    front = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "QueenCard"))
    back = UIView(frame: self.frame)
    back.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.contentView.addSubview(back)

    if showingBack {
        NSLog("showBack")
        UIView.transitionFromView(back, toView: front, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
        showingBack = false
    } else {
        UIView.transitionFromView(front, toView: back, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
        showingBack = true
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cells are being reused. When scrolling up, and a cell is goes out of view, this cell is reused at the bottom of the view. In your case a flipped cell is being reused. What you would like to do is un-flip the cell before it is reused.

Before a cell is reused, iOS calls the method [prepareForReuse()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse), this is where you would un-flip the cell, or reset any custom property.

In your case it could look something like this (untested code) :

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

    if showingBack {
        UIView.transitionFromView(back, toView: front, duration: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, completion: nil)
        showingBack = false
    }
}
```

This way, when the cell is reused it will be un-flipped. If you would like flipped cells to stay flipped, you should keep the flipped-state in your model.